# Update some items in an array with immer.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immer.js

I'm using the redux library and in a reducer I just want to update a state property (rowData).

I want to update some items in that array.

```js
export const initialState = {
    grid:{
        rowData: [],
    }
};
```

```
const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {     
        case UPDATE_ROWS:
                  var rowsToUpdate = action.rowsToUpdate;
                  rowsToUpdate.map(rowToUpdate => {
                  const index = draft.grid.rowData.findIndex(rowData =>{
                        return  rowToUpdate.id === rowData.id;
                  });
                  if(index >= 0){
                     draft.grid.rowData[index] = rowToUpdate.priorityStep1;
                  }

          });
```

I'm having trouble in doing this operation with immer.js.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you describe the trouble with your code?

Comment: What kinda of trouble? Please, post a more complete example.

Comment: I update the code to show what I tried. draft.shareGrid.rowData doesn't give me the data. I'm wrong and I don't know what is the way to solve this problem.

Comment: What I can see is that you are mutating the received parameter, this is one of the most important rules with redux, don't mutate your state but copy it and alter the copy.

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox? It looks like immer is not necessarily needed at this scenario, so a detailed explanation on what you are trying to achieve with some sample data will help.